# Getting a value from url and using it in sql query

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm working on a complex project for a car dealership where I have to create database search based on multiple criteria. The cars in the database are divided into 3 types - let's call them A, B and C. Let's say that the value of A=1, B=2, C=3. The url would look something like `index.php?type_id=1` . The working search code so far is as follows.

In `index.php` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#car').on('change',function(){
        var carID = $(this).val();
        if(carID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'marque_id='+carID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#model').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#model').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#model').attr("disabled");
            $('#energy').attr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
</script>

$type_id = $_GET['type_id];

$query = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT marque_name,a.marque_id FROM vehicule_marque as a INNER JOIN vehicule as b WHERE b.type_id = '$type_id' AND a.marque_id = b.marque_id  order by marque_name");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

<div>Select car</div>
    <select name="car" id="car" required >
        <option value="">Select Car</option>
        <?php
        if($rowCount > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                echo '<option value="'.$row['marque_id'].'">'.$row['marque_name'].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">Car not available</option>';
        }

        ?>
    </select>


    <div>Select car model</div>
    <select name="model" id="model" disabled>
        <option value=""><!--Select car first--></option>
    </select>
```

In `ajaxData.php` :

```
if(isset($_POST["marque_id"]) && !empty($_POST["marque_id"])) {
    //Get all state data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT a.modele_id, modele_name, a.marque_id FROM vehicule_modele as a INNER JOIN vehicule as b  WHERE a.marque_id = ".$_POST['marque_id']." AND b.type_id = '$type_id' AND b.marque_id = a.marque_id AND b.modele_id = a.modele_id ORDER BY modele_name ");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display model list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select model</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['modele_id'].'">'.$row['modele_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Model not available</option>';
    }
}
```

The problem is with taking the `type_id` value and using it in `ajaxData.php` query in order to show the model once the customer selected a car brand. In `index.php`, I `GET` the value from the url successfully (I tried echoing it and it worked), but then I can't get it to work in the other query - it keeps on showing only "Model not available" option. I tried putting inside the script the `$type_id` into a new variable, but this didn't work either. I'm not sure what I'm missing. If I remove the type_id condition, everything works perfectly. If anyone has any idea how to fix this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `ajaxData.php` __knows nothing__ about your `$type_id = $_GET['type_id'];`. So, you have to pass `$type_id` to `ajaxData.php` explicitly.

Comment: You need to pass the variable in the Ajax request for the script to use it.

Comment: Does that mean I have to `GET` it or put it in a new variable inside `ajaxData.php` ? @u_mulder

Comment: Please read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and consider using parametrized queries. Your application is vulnerable here.

Comment: You should pass this variable to `ajaxData.php`, via GET or POST, I don't care.

Comment: I did try `$id=$_GET['type_id']` inside `ajaxData.php` before posting this, and in the querry `b.type_id='$id'` but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand that request to url `index.php?type_id=1` and request to url `ajaxData.php` are **different** requests and know **nothing** about each other.

So, if you try to access `$_GET['type_id']` in `ajaxData.php` you will **obviously** receive **nothing**, because `$_GET` is **empty** in `ajaxData.php`. If you send request to `ajaxData.php?type_id=42` you **will get** `42` as `$_GET['type_id']`.

So, you if you want to use some `$_GET` or `$_POST` data in `ajaxData.php` you **must** send this data **explicitly**.

It can be either:

```
url:'ajaxData.php?type_id=' + yourValue,  
// access it with $_GET['type_id']
```

or

```
data:'marque_id='+carID+'&type_id='+yourValue,
// access it with $_POST['type_id']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I actually tried something like this with data, but I didn't write it correctly, so thank you for showing me the right way to do it.